# How to exclude the null value in an object using every method in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I am having a json object which is by default has 12 objects user can add value to the object.If the user adds value only for 2 objects and when i tried to use every() it returns false even though the condition which i have set as true because of the empty values in the object.

I would like to know how to exclude an object which has empty value.

```
vm.schemeApply.documents.filter(function(doc) {
  $log.log("base64", base64MimeType(doc.url));
  if (doc.url && doc.url.length > 0) {
    return (
      base64MimeType(doc.url) === ".png" ||
      base64MimeType(doc.url) === ".pdf" ||
      base64MimeType(doc.url) === ".jpeg"
    );
  }
});
```

Array Example:

```
[
  {name: "Test1", url: "AADDfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf"},
  {name: "Test2", url: "AADDfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf"},
  {name: "Test3", url: ""},
  {name: "Test4", url: ""},
  {name: "Test5", url: ""},
  {name: "Test6", url: ""},
  {name: "Test7", url: ""},
  {name: "Test8", url: ""},
  {name: "Test9", url: ""},
  {name: "Test10", url: ""} 
]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) casting the value of `url` to **true** or **false** using `!!` like `newArr = arr.filter(o=>(!!o.url)):`, or just:

```js
const arr = [
    {name: "Test1", url: "AADDfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf"},
    {name: "Test2", url: "AADDfdfdfdfdfdfdfdfdf"},
    {name: "Test3", url: ""},
    {name: "Test4", url: ""},
    {name: "Test5", url: ""},
    {name: "Test6", url: ""},
    {name: "Test7", url: ""},
    {name: "Test8", url: ""},
    {name: "Test9", url: ""},
    {name: "Test10", url: ""} 
  ]


  newArr = arr.filter(o=>(o.url))

  console.log(newArr)
```

[every()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) is not useful for you in this situation I think, because returns true (or false) whether:

> all elements in the array pass the test implemented by
>   the provided function.

Comment: Isn't OP's function already doing this? He has additional mime-type checks inside the "url exists" check. His error is that his filter callback is not returning anything.

Comment: @FranCarstens yes, but OP adds `doc.url.length > 0` that I think is useless, and asks about every()

Answer (score 0):

this may be not the best solution but :

```js
var returnValue = false;
vm.schemeApply.documents.filter(function(doc) {
     $log.log("base64", base64MimeType(doc.url));
     if (doc.url && doc.url.length > 0) {
       let condition = ((base64MimeType(doc.url) === ".png") || (base64MimeType(doc.url) === ".pdf") || (base64MimeType(doc.url) === ".jpeg"));
       if(condition) {
          returnValue = true;
       }
       return condition;
     }
     return returnValue;
  });
```

what i've done here is if only one object exist then the next object with empty url will return `true`

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're returning in the wrong spot. Your if statement receives a return, but you're never returning anything to the filter method. A slightly more terse example:

```js
const docs = [
  {name: "Test1", url: "123"},
  {name: "Test2", url: "124"},
  {name: "Test3", url: ""},
  {name: "Test4", url: ""},
  {name: "Test5", url: ""},
  {name: "Test6", url: ""},
  {name: "Test7", url: ""},
  {name: "Test8", url: ""},
  {name: "Test9", url: ""},
  {name: "Test10", url: ""} 
]

const result = docs.filter(function(doc) {
  return !!doc.url && (
      doc.url === '123' ||
      doc.url === '124'
    )
});

console.log(result)
```

Or, if you prefer using the if statement, you could also write it as:

```
 const result = docs.filter(function(doc) {
  const hasDoc = !!doc.url
  let result
  if (hasDoc) { result = 
      doc.url === '123' ||
      doc.url === '124'
  }
  return result
})
```